# AWS CodeArtifact HTTP API returns: Invalid name for a Snapshot

Tags: curl, aws-codeartifact

I'm trying to publish a file to AWS CodeArtifact using curl, as described here: [AWS: Publishing with curl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-curl.html)

This works until I try to publish a SNAPSHOT version, e.g. add -SHAPSHOT to the end of the version.  When I append -SNAPSHOT to the version I get

> Invalid name for a Snapshot build asset: 'packageName-version-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz'

Of course, replace "packageName" and "version" with the actual package name and version strings.

The curl command looks like this:

```
curl --request PUT "${repositoryEndpointAttainedFromAwsCli}/${repositoryName}/${packageNamespaceWithSlashesInsteadOfDots}/${packageName}/${packageVersion}/${packageName}-${packageVersion}.tar.gz" --user "aws:${authTokenAttainedFromAwsCli}" --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --data-binary @package.tar.gz
```

When ${packageVersion} ends with -SNAPSHOT I get the error.  When ${packageVersion} doesn't end with -SNAPSHOT the publish works.

I need to publish snapshots. So what am I'm I doing wrong with the snapshot versioning?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the example on the link you listed for the SNAPSHOT case and it is currently under investigation:

For now, try the following format:

```
curl --request PUT https://my_domain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven/maven-central-store/com/basicapp/myapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT --user "aws:$CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN" --data-binary @/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the same issue, CodeArtifact has specific requirements for snapshot artifact naming that cannot be circumvented:

> AWS CodeArtifact supports publishing and consuming Maven snapshots. **Unique snapshots that use a time-based version number are the only snapshots that are supported.** CodeArtifact doesn't support non-unique snapshots that are generated by Maven 2 clients. You can publish a supported Maven snapshot to any CodeArtifact repository.

See more details on handling snapshots in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-snapshots.html).